# Can't resize window of scene builder

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0.77, on 81 SceneBuilder doesn't work.
My problem is, when I launch Scene Builder I cannot resize main window app.
How can I resolved this problem?

Edit.
Scene Builder can be resized when I launch it from Eclipse.

Comment: This is a bug in JavaFX on Linux whereas after opening a popup, the window may not be resized. Since Gluon's version of SceneBuilder has a nagging popup requesting you to sign up, this happens every time. You can open a new window after closing the popup, which should be free of this inconvenience.

Comment: Will they fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I always open SceneBuilder from IDE "file>rightClick>open in sceneBuilder". In that way bug never appears and you can create new windows, open files and other.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with ubuntu 16.04 gnome desktop. I disabled hide top bar in my gnome plugins and this solve resize/maximize scennebuilder when I load an fxml file.